# TypeScript: Firestore withConverter and refrences

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am fairly new to Firestore/Firebase. I have this Album class that can hold a reference to a parent Album

```
export class Album {
    constructor(public id: string,
                public title: string,
                public parent: Album | null,
    ) {
    }
}

export class AlbumConverter implements FirestoreDataConverter<ImageData> {
    toFirestore(album: Album): firebase.firestore.DocumentData {
        return {
            id: album.id,
            title: album.title,
            parent: album.parent ?.....
```

My question is, how should I implement the `toFirestore` and `fromFirestore`? what's the proper way to use `DataConverter` when dealing with references?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You must pass a [DocumentReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference) as `parent`.

To get the reference you can do for exemple :

```
   function getRef = (id: string): Promise<any> {
        return new Promise<Track>(async (resolve, reject) => {
            const query = this.db.collection(this.collectionPath).where('id', '==', id); 
            const querySnapshot = await query.get();

            if (querySnapshot.empty) {
                return reject("not found")
            }

            return resolve(querySnapshot.docs[0].ref);
        });
    }
```

And then :

```
const parentRef = await getRef(parentId);

const albumConverter = {
    toFirestore: (album: Album) => {
        return {
            id: album.id,
            title: album.title,
            parent: parentRef
        }
    }
}
```